# More efficiently process cartesian product of AoA in Perl

Tags: r, performance, perl, cartesian-product

I am working to calculate a value for the probability of two items in a group having the same value (similar situation to the birthday problem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

To do this I have 24 sets of three values. Each item in the group will have one value of the 3 from each of the 24 sets.

The calculation I need to do is get the sum of the square of the products for all possible iterations of these values.

This sort of iteration is obviously very intensive given the necessarily iterative nature.

With input from SE already I now have:

```
#!perl;
use List::Util qw(reduce);
use Set::CrossProduct;

my @array = ( ## AoA containing values for caluculation, cut-down to allow benchmarking
#   [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],  x11 more in full set
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33],
    [0.33, 0.33, 0.33]
);

$val = 0;
my $iterator = Set::CrossProduct->new(\@array);
while (my $tuple = $iterator->get) {
    $freq = reduce { $a * $b } @$tuple;
    $val += ($freq*$freq);
}

$toprint=sprintf("%.50e", $val);
print $toprint;
```

Based on a quick benchmark on the subset of the 13 sets as in the code above, I estimate that this will take ~45 days to run the full 24 sets on my PC. Are there any suggestions as to how this performance may be improved. I'm not looking for miracles, I'd be happy with it taking under a week....

I'm not emotionally invested in Perl, so could try to shift to another language if there would be *significant* performance benefits.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT: Added R tag as that's probably the second best for my being able to implement the solution.

Comment: the reduce call is going to be *significantly* more expensive than just `$tuple->[0] * $tuple->[1] * $tuple->[2] ...`

Comment: `$freq =1; $freq *= $_ for @$tuple;` instead of `$freq = reduce { $a * $b } @$tuple;`

Comment: @ysth that gets it down to 42 days worth, _signficant_, but still a way to go sadly.

Comment: I assume your actual data is not all `0.33`s.

Comment: No it's not, all the values however are decimals that sum to 1 across the set, so I just simplified for an MWE.

If they were, $1/3^24$ would be far easier to do.

Comment: @mpapec: Why did you tag this question with all those languages? Even if OP has interest in other languages, your choice seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: @Zeta I've tagged platforms which are better at parallelism and mathematics, and OP wants significant performance benefits. Can you provide better perl solution?

Comment: @mpapec: I would be surprised if I even understood a single expression pearl ;). However, in this case, we could simple strip the [tag:pearl] tag, since he's only interested in [tag:performance] and [tag:cartesian-product], which might be a more objective solution.

Comment: @Zeta perhaps, but that would see a lot less people, according to tag followers. I know some perl, so leave it to my judgement. :)

Comment: Your problem space is large (3^24). You could parallelize your solution, or you could reduce the problem space.

Comment: The problem spaced is fixed due to my purposes. Parellelisation is an option as I do have access to a HPC cluster. It's unclear to me how it could be run in parallel, it seems problematic to divide the subsets of the cartesian product for seperate runs, though this may be my naiveté.

Comment: I know next-to-nothing about this type of problem, but in my googling found [somebody who said](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/woJZbxs8KE0): "It is rarely practical to do exhaustive comparisons on datasets of this size...The method used is to heuristically prune the cartesian product set and only examine pairs that have a high likelihood of being near." Perhaps that's helpful, perhaps not.

Comment: And along those lines, it might be beneficial to post a question on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) to see if you can improve your algorithm.

Comment: The Perl number-crunching library PDL should help.

Answer (score 3):

This type of problem is my cup of tea. Here are my thoughts:

---

## Let's take a step back

The key objective here is to reduce the amount of time taken to evaluate the results. You have 3^24 = 282+ billion evaluations that need to be performed which cannot be avoided. However, there are a few tricks that can be employed to make lighter work of the problem (the comments also allude to some of these):

1. Parallelize the effort to cut down the time needed
2. Avoid repeated calculations

---

## Parallelized computing

#### Divide and conquer

The key to unlocking parallelization (as has already been mentioned) is to divide the effort into smaller segments. In the context of this problem, the tuples need to be divided into more manageable chunks.

If I have a quad-core processor, I might want to split the tuples into four baskets:

```
my ( @baskets, $iter );
push @{ $baskets[ $iter++ % 4 ] }, $_ for $iterator->combinations;
```

This kind of functionality is quite readily rolled into a sub:

```
sub segment {

  my $num_segments = shift;
  my ( @baskets, $iter );

  push @{ $baskets[ $iter++ % $num_segments ] }, $_ for @_;
  return @baskets;
}

my @jobs = segment( 4, $iterator->combinations );
```

#### Launch in parallel

The use of threads should be adequate here since the per-tuple computation is lightweight (refer to [`perldoc perlthrtut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html) for more information on how to use threads in Perl):

```
use threads;                                            # imports threads module

sub work {                                              # What each thread will run

  my @tuples = @_;

  my $sum;
  for my $tuple ( @tuples ) {

    my $freq = 1;
    $freq *= $_ for @$tuple;
    $sum += $freq * $freq;
  }

  return $sum;
}

my @threads = map threads->new( \&work, @$_ ), @jobs;  # Create and launch threads
                                                       # with different tuple sets

my $grand_total;
$grand_total += $_->join for @threads;                 # Accumulate sub-totals
```

---

## Kill *n* birds with 1 stone (multiplied by *n*)

**Disclaimer:** The effectiveness of this solution increases as the number of discrete probabilities increases. It is not easy to judge whether this proposal would actually reduce the time to get the result.

Assuming 2 d.p., there can only ever be 100 possible different values across all tuples (I guess this is where the Birthday Problem comes into play). Given that you have 24 probabilities in each tuple, I imagine the likelihood of two tuples yielding the same frequency is high (a statistician can confirm this assumption). This can be demonstrated with a simple example in which I've limited the number of probabilities to just 3:

```
[ 0.33, 0.45, 0.22 ], # Tuple A
.
.
.
[ 0.45, 0.22, 0.33 ], # Tuple B
```

Here, tuples A and B will return the same value for `$freq`. If we count the number of times this `$freq` value would appear, one can simply compute `$freq` once and multiply it by the number of "repeat" tuples (and thereby killing many tuples with one stone).

This would involve detecting the number of repeats:

```
my %seen;
for my $tuple ( $iterator->combinations ) {

    my @sorted = sort @$tuple;
    my $tuple_as_string = "@sorted";

    $seen{$tuple_as_string}{count}++;

    next unless exists $seen{$tuple_as_string}{freq};

    my $freq = 1;
    $freq *= $_ for @$tuple;

    $seen{$tuple_as_string}{freq} = $freq;
}


my $grand_total;
for my $unique ( keys %seen ) {

    my $count = $seen{$unique}{count};
    my $freq = $seen{$unique}{freq};
    $grand_total += $count * $freq * $freq;
}
```

If you wish to combine this idea with parallelization, I would recommend identifying the "unique" tuples first before proceeding with parallelizing the operation.

Comment: `my @jobs = segment( 4, $iterator->combinations );` stores all 282+ billion tuples in main memory, no?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : Memory shouldn't really be a concern here. If it is, you could always use lazy iterator slices provided by [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen#lazy-slices) (I chose to focus on conveying the concept rather than the implementation)

Comment: My first attempted implementation of this took the approach of loading all tuples to memory, rapidly running out of 22 Gib of RAM, so memory if an issue.

Comment: @ReubenJohnPengelly : In that case then you can use `List::Gen` instead of `Set::CrossProduct`

Comment: Using Memoize with DB_File would be a much shorter solution to that problem.